# How to Scrape relevant article text from different websites with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping

So I want to retrieve the paragraphs of certain articles when a user gives an url input. However, most websites like nytimes or google news have also other articles below that article. Or they have other not-relevant paragraphs on the same page. How can I circumvent this so that it would scrape only the relevant article that someone clicked on to read.

```
import urllib,sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from prettyprint import prettyprint as pp 

html = urllib.urlopen(raw_input("Paste the URL of the website here:\n")).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
texts = soup.findAll("p", text=True)
paragraphs = soup.find('article').find("div", {'class': 'storyBody'}).find_all('p') 
 # This works for Google article, as the div class is storyBody so it scrapes
 # the relevant article only. 

def visible(element):
    if element.parent.name in ['style', 'script', '[document]', 'head', 'title']:
        return False
    elif re.match('<!--.*-->', str(element)):
        return False
    return True

visible_texts = filter(visible, texts)
print(visible_texts)

result = pp.pp_str(visible_texts)
```

example websites:

- http://www.zdnet.be/nieuws/188483/binnenkort-eindelijk-4g-internet-op-alle-vliegtuigen/

  http://www.nu.nl/binnenland/4357771/in-hoger-beroep-in-zaak-nicole-van-hurk.html

Which have two different formats. So I'm looking for something generic to implement.

Comment: Can you provide an example URL? Usually the "main"-article and other articles below have different classes and/or id:s so you can filter out the relevant one.

Comment: See example URLs please :)